# MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 22.04 stuck in upgrade loop error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-22.04

MySQL will not start on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server. It was working for a few months but then got caught in the following loop that appears to be due to a server upgrade it tries to run when it starts:

```
2022-11-04T18:40:51.568052Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 8978                         
2022-11-04T18:40:51.581277Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.                                                                 
2022-11-04T18:41:59.849028Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.                                                                   
2022-11-04T18:42:03.102797Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80030' to '80031' started.                                                    
2022-11-04T18:42:54.565027Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'EXECUTE stmt; ' failed with error code = 1091, error message = 'Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists'.|
2022-11-04T18:42:54.569286Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.                                                                           
2022-11-04T18:42:54.569392Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting                                                                                            
2022-11-04T18:42:55.869863Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

My logs are just repeats of those lines over and over again.

From the logs, I am guessing the upgrade script is trying to run a query that requires DROP PRIMARY but I can't find that query.

I have tried rebooting the server and restarting with systemctl. Neither changed the behavior.

I have tried to uninstall mysql-server from the command line but it says that it is only partially installed and then tries to install and run it generating the same errors as above.

When I try to kill it, it just respawns seconds later.

How can I fix this error loop?

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-installing mysql-server but it did not work. I needed to disable mysql, uninstall it, purge it, clear the configs, and THEN reinstall.

I was able to stop the error loop with the following code:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo systemctl disable mysql
sudo apt remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

The disable was key to stopping the loop and the rm from the etc folders did not cause an error on install.

This was found through combining https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781788395809/1/ch01lvl1sec16/uninstalling-mysql-8 and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/completely-uninstall-mysql-server